# Confluent Heun Equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, power-series

Does anyone know any source in which I could find a recurrence relation for the coefficients of the series solution of the Confluent Heun Equation

$$y''+\left( {\gamma\over z}+{\delta\over z-1}+\varepsilon\right)y'+{\alpha z-q\over z(z-1)}y=0$$

around the regular singular point $z=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to start looking would be the book "Heun's Differential Equations" by A. Ronveaux.

Comment: It is easier to write it yourself than to look into Ronveaux book.

Answer (score 1):

According to Maple, the recurrence is

$$ \left( \varepsilon\,n+\alpha \right) a \left( n \right) + \left( {n}^{2}
+ \left( \gamma+\delta-\varepsilon+1 \right) n+\gamma+\delta-\varepsilon-q
 \right) a \left( n+1 \right) + \left( -{n}^{2}+ \left( -\gamma-3
 \right) n-2\,\gamma-2 \right) a \left( n+2 \right) = 0
$$

Comment: Thanks for the computation. I checked, and it's the same as the one appearing in the book suggested in the other answer. I accepted the other answer because I was asking for a source and that's what they gave, but yours was very useful as well, thank you